# pro*c++ oracle ORA-2122 Invalid OPEN or PREPARE for this database connection

Tags: oracle, proc

```
int DbsMainCtl::Fetch(vector<struct QatMainCtrl>& vQatMainCtl)
{
    QatMainCtrl qatMainCtl;

    memset(dbHost,0x00,sizeof(dbHost));
    strcpy(dbHost,DBHOST);

    EXEC SQL AT :dbHost DECLARE cur_QAT_MAIN_CTL CURSOR FOR SELECT BIN_NAME,ARGUMENT,SRC_ID FROM qat_main_ctl WHERE ENABLED='1';
    if(sqlca.sqlcode!= 0)
    {
        return sqlca.sqlcode;
    }
    EXEC SQL OPEN cur_QAT_MAIN_CTL;
    if(sqlca.sqlcode!= 0)
    {
        return sqlca.sqlcode;
    }   
    while(1)
    {
        memset(&qatMainCtl,0x00,sizeof(QatMainCtrl));
        memset(&pQatMainCtl,0x00,sizeof(qat_main_ctl_def));
        EXEC SQL FETCH cur_QAT_MAIN_CTL INTO :pQatMainCtl.bin_name:h_bin_name,
                                                :pQatMainCtl.argument:h_argument,
                                                :pQatMainCtl.src_id:h_src_id;
        if(sqlca.sqlcode == 1403)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(sqlca.sqlcode)
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"sql fetch error [%s]\n",sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
            EXEC SQL CLOSE cur_QAT_MAIN_CTL;
            return sqlca.sqlcode;
        }

        DbsCommon::CommonRTrim(pQatMainCtl.bin_name);
        DbsCommon::CommonRTrim(pQatMainCtl.argument);
        DbsCommon::CommonRTrim(pQatMainCtl.src_id);

        memcpy(&qatMainCtl,&pQatMainCtl,sizeof(QatMainCtrl));
        vQatMainCtl.push_back(qatMainCtl);
    }
    EXEC SQL CLOSE cur_QAT_MAIN_CTL;
    return sqlca.sqlcode;
}
```

On 'EXEC SQL FETCH...',the sqlca.sqlcode return -2122,It's Invalid OPEN or PREPARE for this database connection error.

I have searched the google,the recommend solution is close the cursor,but I have closed all cursor.

I have tried to change cursor name but no effect.I don't know why this problem occurs.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on Windows? And which DB version? MoS note 1395413.1 suggests `EXEC SQL AT :dbHost FETCH`, though it also looks like it expects you to need to use `AT` for the open and close too, and your open appears to be OK. Does adding `AT` :dbHost` to those statement stop it erroring?

Comment: I change OPEN and CLOSE statement to EXEC SQL AT :dbHost FETCH.....,it also return -2122 error.

Comment: I also tried add AT :dbHost on OPEN,CLOSE and FETCH statement,also -2122 error.

Comment: I use Centos7 64bit and Oracle 12.1